# Find element by text inside another element using UISelector query

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium, android-uiautomator

I have the following code snippet and the screenshot attached.

```
String query = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className(\"androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView\"))" +
                ".scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"Test Group\"))";
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator (query).click ();
```

What I want is to find an element with the text "Test Group" using UISelector, but inside the RecyclerView only (not searching the whole app source). What I get is the element inside search field instead (not in the RecyclerView).

Please advice. I know that I can get all searched elements using `findElements(By.id("name"))`. But I want to use UI selector in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `UiSelector` you can use chaining:

```
String query = "new UiScrollable(resourseIdMatches(\".*recycler_view\")).scrollIntoView(resourseIdMatches(\".*recycler_view\")).childSelector(text(\"Text Group\")))";
```

In addition `new UiSelector...` part can be omitted. Appium does support this syntax.